# UIPopoverController is not presenting on "presentViewController"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, popup

I am developing iPad application. In this application i am showing ViewController in presentViewController using this following code

> `[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];`

After that i am showing popup using UIPopoverController in that  presentviewController with out dismissing "vc".  so that i am getting the issue following issue **`Warning: Attempt to present <SelectionListViewController: 0x7b439960>  on <ViewController: 0x7a341e00> which is already presenting (null)`**

So that the popup is not presenting on ViewController. how to solve this issue. This is existing project now i need to fix this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Present in this manner...

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;


            UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = [vc popoverPresentationController];
            popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
            popController.sourceView = self.view;


[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
                        }];
```

Comment: try this
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
});

Comment: I have Tried both way. But i am getting same issue again

Answer (score 0):

I think presentViewController in a performSelector call will solve your problem.
Try this 2 Methods

```
-(void) present
{
    [self performSelector: @selector(ShowSelectionListViewController) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0];
}

-(void) ShowSelectionListViewController
{
    [self presentViewController:SelectionListViewController animated: true completion: nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should try this one. it worked for me...**

```
if([AppDelegate isIOS8])
        {
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                 ^{[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect
                                              inView:self.view
                            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                            animated:YES];});
        }
        else
        {
            [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect
                                          inView:self.view
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                        animated:YES ];
        }
```